# RoomDB synchronization between Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-room

I have an app which is storing data in Room Database. This is an movie app and when user add new movie to his list, it doesn't work in synchronization. When I close app and open again, list will being updated. Users adding film button is in one fragment, list is in another fragment. They are not in same fragment. It add database without problem but I need to make synchronization between these two fragments.

This is List Fragment.

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView listTitleImage;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    List<MainData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    RoomDB database;
    RecyclerViewFavoritesAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,container,false);
        listTitleImage = v.findViewById(R.id.listTitleImage);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFavorites);

        database = RoomDB.getInstance(v.getContext());

        dataList = database.mainDao().getAll();

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerViewFavoritesAdapter(v.getContext(),dataList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

This is menu click method which includes adding in list.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {


        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuAdd){

            int movie_id = resultList.get(pos).getMovieId();
            String title = resultList.get(pos).getTitle();
            String posterpath = resultList.get(pos).getPoster_path();

            database = RoomDB.getInstance(context);

            MainData mainData = new MainData();

            mainData.setMovie_id(movie_id);
            mainData.setMovie_name(title);
            mainData.setMovie_poster(posterpath);

            int movie_id_in_database = database.mainDao().get_movie_id(movie_id);

            if(movie_id_in_database == 0){
                database.mainDao().insert(mainData);
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "You already have that movie in list !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            return true;

        }
        else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuShowDetails){

            int movieId = resultList.get(pos).getMovieId();
           // Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MovieDetails.class);
           // intent1.putExtra("movie_id",movieId);
           // context.startActivity(intent1);
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The right time to kick of `LiveData`

Comment: There's no logic here that suggests you would receive updates. Definitely take a look at using `LiveData` as @Zain said or an `RxJava` solution if you intend to separate your code into a repository.

Comment: Thank you to both of you, I will check LiveData